# SSRS change Datasource connection String

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone share a SQL Script which simply modify the connection string for a shared datasource in SSRS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, because a SQL script can only be run when connected to a SQL data source.

However, I suspect that what you actually need is an *expression* that can be used for the connection string - something like:

```
="Data Source=" + Parameters!DBName.Value + ";Initial Catalog=ReportDB"
```

Comment: Please can the downvoter leave a comment explaining the reason for the downvote, so that the offered answer can be improved?

Comment: All data sources and their connection strings are stored in the ReportServer database of Reporting Services. So the question may mean how to change a connection string of data source in the ReportServer database via SQL script.

Comment: agree with Ivan above

Comment: @MikeW: The OP has had 6 years to clarify his question. Still, if you think otherwise, why not leave an alternative answer?